# Mosaic Tile effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator

New to graphic design, I'm wondering if there is a way to go about creating this kind of old roman or byzantine era-esque mosaic tile effect in a less time intensive way? I've seen brushes for sale, but can it be done without purchasing any additional materials? Other than mapping out an image block for block, I'm a bit at a loss. I'm using adobe illustrator. [image][image][image]

Comment: Good is very subjective. For some it means with hours of work for some it means immediately

Comment: I've stumbled upon the term *Fauxsaic*. Searching for that yields many examples and tutorials. All of them seems to involve a lot of work.

Comment: Really.. for *many* "old world" or handmade types of images there's no *digital* substitute which *doesn't* require at least an equal amount of manual labor. Sure one can run filters and use plug ins as a "quick fix" to try and get as close as possible, but filters/plug-ins/automation will **never** really match the manual construction. If you want that matched.. it takes *manual* construction albeit digitally.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, No, you cannot recreate roman or byzantine era-esque mosaic tile images in a less time intensive way.

You can apply image effects as shown by other answers with filters in PS or AI. These can give a nice mosaic tile look to your picture but they in no way compare to the mosaics you refer to which are created by hand and artistry. I have seen actual modern tile mosaics that can arguably rival the ancient ones, but again, these are done manually and not by a filter or a click of a button. The same artistry *can be done* digitally but also by the same technique- which is manual shaping and coloring of each tile.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to semi-automate this.  There's a free plugin called [G'MIC](https://gmic.eu/) which works in Photoshop, GIMP, Krita and some other image editors. The example below was done in GIMP. Note: I have no affiliation with the developers of this plugin.

Set up the document by duplicating the image layer, and select the top layer.

Start the plugin (usually located under Filters) and search for "mosaic" and choose "Mosaic A" by samj. It looks a bit rubbish at this stage but you can fix it later. Here are the settings I used.

[image]

After you have done it, Select the bottom layer, and do a curves adjustment to make the background a bit darker.

[image]

Anyway, it's quite nice because as mosaic cells follow the contours of the drawing.

A detail from the finished effect. It's not perfect, but maybe a start. You could perhaps even overlay it with some kind of texture.

[image]

With a concrete texture overlay set to Hard Light, opacity around 20%

[image]

Comment: Interesting enough, one *could* do the same thing in Illustrator with effects on a solid colored image. The Mosaic filter exists in AI. It simply applies a raster texture.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could divide the image area to small pieces and then pick to each piece the right color from an image which is painted separately or it's a photo. A programmer might generate a script for picking the colors automatically. Here's one tutorial how to divide the image area to pieces which have a 3D look and how to colorize the pieces (you find easily many others, too):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLEbssKyOIU

The tutorial doesn't make a plausible Byzantine look. That's because it actually converts a photo - yes, it's done manually, but the tiling still divides a photo to pieces, the forms are not generated by tiling like in the real mosaic.

See the palm trees on an island. The curvatures of tiled sequences obey the curvatures of objects and the sizes and forms are selected so that a limited selection of piece sizes is enough without causing excessive gaps.

The division to tiled pieces should be made manually (you want to avoid it) or it must be done by so clever program that it understands which pieces belong to which object in the original image.

In ordinary graphic programs like Illustrator or Photoshop you must draw the tiled mosaic lines manually to get it right. Pattern brushes can help substantially but that's still far from automatic. You do not convert a photo to mosaic, but draw a new image by tiling pieces along a curve. It's essentially the original mosaic building idea, but happens in your computer  See this tutorial of the brush method in Illustrator:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_KG3Uiec2Q

The image is only a single curve. Tiling something more interesting is much more difficult.